# document.getElementById returns null on a dynaimcally created div

Tags: javascript, html

Something weird is happening here.

**My website is using javascript to create dynamic divs, but although they are entered into the DOM (at least this is what I think), javascript returns null when calling that div.**

---

This is the javscript code which is loaded before **`</body>`**

```js
function AddPlayer(){
    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    createBox(name);
};

function createBox(name){
    var span = document.createElement('span');
        span.id = name;
        span.innerHTML = name;
        document.getElementById("gameArea").appendChild(span);

    var span = document.createElement('span');
        span.id = "score-" + name;
        span.innerHTML = "0";
        document.getElementById("gameArea").appendChild(span);

    var inputSText = document.createElement('input');
        inputSText.type = "button";
        inputSText.value = "Add Points";
        inputSText.onclick = function(){AddPoints(name);};
        document.getElementById("gameArea").appendChild(inputSText);
};

function AddPoints(player){
    document.load(document.getElementById("#score-"+ player).innerHTML = "Please work");
};
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Game Score Keeper</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Game Score Keeper</h2>
    <input type="text" id="name" />
    <input type="button" value="Add Player" onclick="AddPlayer()" />

    <div id="gameArea">

    </div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Here is the jsfiddle of this project http://jsfiddle.net/jwmm6rk7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the id of the element to `document.getElementById`. That is, without the hash (`#`) symbol.

```
function AddPoints(player) {
    document.load(document.getElementById("score-" + player).innerHTML = "HELLO");
};
```

Comment: Bro thanks! That was some really noob mistake. Funny how i didn't notice it. Again thanks.

Comment: lookslike you were jQuery user

Comment: Nope. That document.load() thing I used was to test if maybe using that, the Id would get picked up, and I had no idea that that had to do with jQuery. Still getting the true hang of javascript.

Answer (score 0):

lookslike you were jQuery user, you used `#` and `name` instead of `player`

```
function AddPoints(player) {
    document.getElementById("score-" + player).innerHTML = "HELLO";
};
```

Comment: Yeah. I honestly noticed that other mistake after I posted this question. That was the last part and was done at 3 in the morning where i was tired and didn't notice it.